# how to put images in the corner of the embed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, bots

How can I put an image on top of the embed like this using links?

[image]

For example, with an imgur link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVP2L.jpg

Comment: can you please share some code where you want to add the image?

Comment: Well, I haven't started making the code yet, but it's a command to show the bot information

Comment: It would be easy for us to solve a problem if you write the code first, otherwise we are unable to solve a problem without knowing the context

Comment: We are not here to write your code for you. Please include a code so we can _help_ you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you want, but `MessageEmbed().setThumbnail('url')` should do that.

To dynamically get a user's profile pic you could do:

```
let user = client.users.cache.get('id');
let avatar = user.displayAvatarUrl()
```

Comment: It should be [`setThumbnail()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed?scrollTo=setThumbnail), not `addThumbnail()`